# Grails GSP <g:set> tag set as integer?

Tags: grails, gsp

Using Grails' GSP `<g:set>` tag, is it possible to specify the type of the variable? I want to declare an integer variable, but `<g:set>` always declares a sting. For example:

```
<g:set var="x" value="100"/>
${x.getClass()}
${x+23}
```

results in

```
class java.lang.String
10023
```

I'd like to declare `x` as an integer. I noticed that using the JSP tag `<% int x=100; %>` results in:

```
class java.lang.Integer
123
```

Is there a way to do this the Grails/GSP way?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the ${} syntax when defining the `value`.  For example:

```
<g:set var="x" value="${100}"/>
```

You can see [the tag doc for g:set](http://gsp.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/set.html) for more info.

Comment: Is is the preferred way to set variables than doing `<% x = 100 %>`?

Answer (score 2):

Just as an additional comment for someone who comes across this since it is the only useful result on the Internet for  and casting/Int/Sring/etc. This example works in the case of variables:

```
<g:set var="printLeft" value="${offer?.metaInfo?.redeemPrintY as Integer}"/>
<g:set var="printTop" value="${offer?.metaInfo?.redeemPrintX as Integer}"/>
<g:set var="printWidth" value="${offer?.metaInfo?.redeemPrintW as Integer}"/>
<g:set var="printHeight" value="${offer?.metaInfo?.redeemPrintH as Integer}"/>
```

...

```
<area shape="rect" coords="${printLeft},${printTop},${printLeft+printWidth},${printTop+printHeight}" onClick="printOffer();" />
```